# excel skip over cells based on variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a budgeting spreadsheet that has a different replacement cycle for equipment and I want to visualize when everything will be scheduled to be replaced.

Column 1=name, Column 2=deployed, Column 3=expected life, Column 4=retire date, Column 5=price

I want to have another table next to it that shows the next several deploy dates (for the next 15 years) based on the expected life. Right now, I'm having to manually count over X number of cells and enter in the price and then count over again.... for each row.

I know there has to be a automated way to do this, but I'm new to excel macros and I've looked at several functions, but can't get anything figured out. What functions should I be looking at?

Comment: How do you skip over columns? i.e. each column represents 1 month? 1 year? 3 years?

Comment: Each column will represent a year. So if a device needs to be replaced every 4 years, it will have a price in one column, and then have 3 blank columns, and then the price again in the 4th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula like:

```
=IF((G$1-YEAR($B2))/$C2=ROUND((G$1-YEAR($B2))/$C2,0),$E2,"")
```

Should do the trick

(the above for column G, it is assumed the year is in `G1`)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I was trying to look at a macro to fill in cells. I didn't realize I could just use an if statement in every cell to do the same. Thanks!


Any idea how to make it work with a fiscal year instead of calendar year?

Comment: I believe `=IF(DATEDIF($B2,G1,"y")/$C2=ROUND(DATEDIF($B2,G1,"y")/$C2,0),$E2,"")` will do that but can't check on the machine I'm on at the moment